# AWS Workspaces client on Ubuntu give display error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-workspaces

Im trying to connect to my Amazon Workspace using the Workspace client on Ubuntu. I keep getting  this. I can connect no problem from my windows machine at work, but keep getting Display Error at home on my linux machine.  [image: Error Message].

Comment: Can you switch on [advanced logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-troubleshooting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble but solved the problem. Please try following process.

1. Uninstalled AWS.
2. Re-start PC and installed AWS again.
3. Wait for couple of hours. while you waiting, try to keep pushing Refresh button or re-start AWS again and again untill the windows shows log in screen.Because  it may take some time to clear old registration information and refresh it in the host side according my IT dept says.

Anyway, I've sent the log files to the AWS help desk and are waiting for their reply.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here we can not assume that it is not working because of so and so reasons, instead we should exactly get to know the root cause for this error. So in order to get the RCA, check the log files present in this directory:

```
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Amazon Web Services\Amazon WorkSpaces\logs
```

So, for me, it was showing the AWS URL access was forbidden.